# Remove users stored under "Web Browsing With Google Smarts"

Tags: google-chrome

Google (via Chrome) is somehow caching anyone that logged in with a Gmail account and associating it with my Chrome Browser.   Pictures and logins are now displayed in Chrome by going to:

Settings->"Web Browsing with Google Smarts"

There is no obvious way to delete the data displayed here and disable this feature.  Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm using MacOS with Chrome v 68.0.3440.106

Comment: I am using 68.0.3440.106 on win10 and started having it too just now... This is SO annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Go to: chrome://flags/#account-consistency , which is:

**Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar**

When enabled, the browser manages signing in and out of Google accounts. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

**Disable that**.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Once you do the above, you then have to clear your history. Then you'll not be logged in anymore.

Comment: Your answer worked for me.   Not sure who downvoted you, but the data is correct.    Does the browser still cache those accounts somewhere even though it no longer displays them?    It seems like a gaping security hole.    What if someone for instance was using a library computer?    Thanks for the help.

Comment: The new version of Chrome ( 69.0.3497.92) still shows my picture if I am logged into gmail.  So even with this setting, it's still secretly correlating browser activity to users.